# I’m trying to copy array but both of them has the same link

Tags: python, arrays, copy

I’m using python 3.9.5.
My code is

```
a = [[0,1],[1,2]]
b = a
b[1] = [4,5]
```

Both of the variables are [[0,1],[4,5]] now. But i don’t want to apply changes to variable a. What should i do? I’ve tried to use the c = b statement but it didn’t help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can be found using a simple google search... However, what you want is ```b = a.copy()```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very useful function that python has for arrays. You can use `a.copy()` to produce an exact copy of the array. I believe `b = a.copy()` would solve your problem.